# How to create correlation matrix only for specific columns combination using python?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I have Three columns Hour, Factor(affect car parking), ParkingSpaces.I am able to draw correlation matrix but it is calculation correlation among all combination and I want to display one correlation matrix of all 5 different files but correlation among those columns only.

[image: Correlation Matrix]

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
sns.set(style="darkgrid")

Creche_Holiday =pd.read_csv("D:\Data Analysis\Practicum\DCU car parking data\New folder\Creche_Holiday.csv")
Creche_Reading = pd.read_csv("D:\Data Analysis\Practicum\DCU car parking data\New folder\Creche_Reading.csv")  
Creche_Study = pd.read_csv("D:\Data Analysis\Practicum\DCU car parking data\New folder\Creche_Study.csv")  
Creche_Working = pd.read_csv("D:\Data Analysis\Practicum\DCU car parking data\New folder\Creche_Working.csv")  
Creche_Exam = pd.read_csv("D:\Data Analysis\Practicum\DCU car parking data\New folder\Creche_Exam.csv")


catted = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [Creche_Working,Creche_Holiday,Creche_Reading,Creche_Study,Creche_Exam]],
                   axis=1, keys=['Working','Holiday', 'Reading', 'Study','Exam'])

catted = catted.rename_axis(['Creche', 'Parking'], axis=1)

corrmat = catted.corr()
# Generate a mask for the upper triangle
mask = np.zeros_like(corrmat, dtype=np.bool)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 11))

# Generate a custom diverging colormap
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220,10,as_cmap=True)

#sns.heatmap(corrmat, vmax=.3, center=0,square=True, linewidths=.5, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5})
# Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
sns.heatmap(corrmat,fmt=".2g",annot=True,cmap=cmap,linewidths=1,cbar=True,vmin=0, vmax=1,center=0,mask=mask)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `drop` method of the dataframe to both drop the rows and columns you do not wish to plot in your heat map.

Consider the following dataframe with 4 total columns of which only two need to be plotted.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1],[3,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5]]).T)
df.columns = ['Value','column_to_drop','Stuff','other_column_to_drop']
```

Results in this dataframe.

```
Value   column_to_drop  Stuff   other_column_to_drop
1   5   3   1
2   4   5   2
3   3   6   3
4   2   7   4
5   1   8   5
```

Quite clearly We want to remove `column_to_drop` and `other_column_to_drop` from the final heatmap.

to do this you need to run the following code. first create the correlation matrix again. After creating the correlation matrix we drop column_to_drop and other_column_to_drop from both the rows and the columns of the correlation matrix.

```
corr_df=df.corr()
heatmap_df=corr_df.drop(['column_to_drop','other_column_to_drop']).drop(['column_to_drop','other_column_to_drop'],axis=1)
```

Then we can simply create the heatmap on this final dataframe.

```
sns.heatmap(heatmap_df)
```

Resulting in this heatmap.
[image]

You can of course choose to do any additional steps on heatmap_df prior to plotting. Like creating a mask to not plot out the same values twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot.It helped me.

Comment: It helped you as in solved the problem? Or are you still having issues?  If you still have issues I can edit my answer.